# What is the maximum number of files that can be included in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, zip

I am building an iPhone app which uses a large number of small data files.  When the total number of files in the app is less than 64K, everything complies and uploads to Apple just fine.  When it is larger it compiles and runs on the simulator but fails to Validate when using the Xcode Organiser to prepare the app for upload.  The error is as follows:

Fails validation phase with error  "(null) is not a valid zip file: ZipContainer files: unable go to first file (-1)"

So, is there a way to fix the Zip utility, or are Apple imposing a limit here?

Comment: What kind of files are you including? Why does it have to be that many?

Comment: Why would you need 64K files?

Comment: If you want to include 64K number of files in your bundle, you should seriously re-think the architecture of your project. Did you consider for example some kind of database?

Answer (score 0):

Why not merge the data in these huge amount of files in an array of objects?